# How to avoid the throttle limit for a particular call of LinkedIn API in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I am integrating LinkedIn in my app. I am posting message to my connection which is working properly. But the problem is when I post message multiple times say 15 message within a time duration it is returning throttle limit error:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Throttle limit for calls to this resource is reached.",
  "requestId": "J69QX565O6",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1357802749431
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used up your daily data limit!

See API usage restrictions @ [Throttle Limits](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits)

The documentations states you can send 10 messages per user account daily or up to 40 messages daily if executing with a developer account (you can add yourself or others as a dev in the LinkedIn [Application Config Section](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer)). You application has a 5k global limit for message transfer daily as well. There is no way around this to the best of my knowledge as it is a hard limit set by LinkedIn